# Can I include sub-config files in my mercurial .hgrc?

Tags: python, mercurial, hgrc, dotfiles

I want to keep my main `.hgrc` in revision control, because I have a fair amount of customization it in, but I want to have different author names depending on which machine I'm using (work, home, &c.).

The way I'd do this in a bash script is to source a host-local bash script that is ignored by Mercurial, but I'm not sure how to do this in the config file format Mercurial uses.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do this using the not-often-used but been-there-awhile include syntax.

Put your machine specific stuff in your `~/.hgrc` and then include a constant-across-all-systems boilerplate config file.  Example:

```
[ui]
username=You <you@somewhere>

%include .hgrc-boilerplate
```

Track the .hgrc-boilerplate file in revision control.

See the [hgrc man page](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) for more details.